# boost matrix with relic

Tags: c++, boost, relic

I'm trying to use a boost matrix of fb_t, which is a [relic](https://code.google.com/p/relic-toolkit/) object that represents element of finite field. Here is how fb_t is defined from the doc:

```
typedef uint64_t dig_t
typedef align dig_t fb_t[FB_DIGS+PADDING(FB_BYTES)/(FB_DIGIT/8)]
```

and here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

extern "C" {
#include <relic.h>
}
#include "relic_test.h"

using namespace std;
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<fb_t> matrix;

int main(void) {
    core_init();
    fb_param_set_any();
    fb_param_print();

    matrix mat(2,2);

   core_clean();
   return 0;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Compiling: main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp:16,
                 from /home/Foo/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::unbounded_array(boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::size_type, const ALLOC&) [with T = unsigned int [4]; ALLOC = std::allocator<unsigned int [4]>; boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::size_type = unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp:131:92:   required from ‘boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T, L, A>::matrix(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T, L, A>::size_type, boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T, L, A>::size_type) [with T = unsigned int [4]; L = boost::numeric::ublas::basic_row_major<>; A = boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<unsigned int [4], std::allocator<unsigned int [4]> >; boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T, L, A>::size_type = unsigned int]’
/home/Foo/main.cpp:21:19:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:71:23: error: functional cast to array type ‘boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<unsigned int [4], std::allocator<unsigned int [4]> >::value_type {aka unsigned int [4]}’
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::iterator_destroy(T*&) [with T = unsigned int [4]; ALLOC = std::allocator<unsigned int [4]>; boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::iterator = unsigned int (*)[4]]’:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:106:25:   required from ‘boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::~unbounded_array() [with T = unsigned int [4]; ALLOC = std::allocator<unsigned int [4]>]’
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp:90:11:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:290:13: error: request for member ‘~boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<unsigned int [4], std::allocator<unsigned int [4]> >::value_type’ in ‘* i’, which is of non-class type ‘unsigned int [4]’
```

I'm not quite sure what the error message is about. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think `boost::ublas` supports arrays as value types. The error message makes me think it's trying to do something like `ValueType(value)`, which isn't valid if `ValueType` is an array because arrays cannot be copied.

Comment: @DavidBrown I suspected something similar. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: You could wrap `fb_t` in a class that constructs and copies it correctly. Or you could replace it with `std::array`.

Comment: @DavidBrown Exactly what I was afraid of. In my case, writing my own matrix class seems to be less painful. Thanks for the response. If you repost it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think boost::ublas supports arrays as value types. The error message is likely because arrays are not copyable. To get around this you could wrap `fb_t` in a class:

```
struct fb_t_wrapper {
    fb_t value;
};
```

Or use `std::array`

```
using fb_t_array = std::array<dig_t, FB_DIGS+PADDING(FB_BYTES)/(FB_DIGIT/8)>;
```